# Finder can find "deploy keys" in Word doc as quoted phrase but not as separate words

Tags: finder

I opened Finder to a folder full of Word documents and searched for `deploy keys`. No hits. I searched for `"deploy keys"` and found it.

In a brand new document, I added the following text:

```
deploy keys
canine man
```

I am able to find this document by searching for `canine man`, `deploy canine`, `deploy`, `keys`, and `"deploy keys"`, but not `deploy keys`. Why?

System is running Mac Monterey 12.4 and Microsoft Word for Mac 16.61.

Comment: Odd. Finds `deploy ke` or `keys deploy` or `<space>deploy keys`. So, putting a space in front is a workaround. Reproducible with TextEdit plain text document. Spotlight (command-space) searches correctly. So must be Finder bug/issue. I don't know why.

Comment: Thank you very much for reproducing and commenting! Now I know it's not just my machine or company, or Word.

Comment: Same issue with beta of macOS Ventura (I was hoping it might be fixed). Have submitted feedback to Apple.

Comment: Wow, thanks Gilby! Do you have a link where I could vote for that? I didn't know where to report it.